# User Customizable Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using `Datatable` in my project.
I am showing 20-25 column in the table.
Is there any option in `data table` where user can him/her self hide the unwanted column and display only the column which he/she want to display.

My Datatable:

```
$("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "order": [],
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        "bProcessing": false,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "searching": false,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation 
        "sort": "position",
        "stateSave": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "ajax": "MyURL"
});
```

Comment: You want to hide the row in any event using jQuery or any other?

Comment: I want to hide entire column not row...

Comment: There is no such option, you can provide scrolling with overflow

Comment: This may help you: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Show/Hide the columns after loading the data in webpage.
Please check the below link, that demonstrate like Show/Hide columns after
loading data in datatable.[Show / hide columns dynamically](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html). May be helpfull.

Comment: Hi Ragesh, Yes, It worked for me. but the problem is after refresh the page again it go back to previous state and user need to again hide the unused column.. :(

Comment: You need to save the hidden columns name in cache or DB ( any other config file ) you want, then hide these columns on next page load.